# Get element if from excel Sheet

Tags: selenium-webdriver, apache-poi

I had created my script to validate my actual result and expected result , .

As there is too many link to validated script will get too much of coding m so i need to convert this into Data Driven Case ,.

Where Webdriver will get URL , xpath ,expected value from excel .

But dont know how to proceed , .

A demo code is much appreciated

Here is my current script :

```
public void test() throws Exception
{
    String home_logo_url="158321";
    String enough_talk_promo="1057406";

    System.out.println("Check for home_logo_url");  
    driver.get(baseUrl);
    String SiteWindow = driver.getWindowHandle(); // get the current window handle
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='logo']/a")).click();
    for (String PromoWindow : driver.getWindowHandles()) 
    {
        driver.switchTo().window(PromoWindow); // switch focus of     WebDriver to the next found window handle (that's your newly opened window)
    }
        String script = "return rlSerial;";
        String value = (String) ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(script);
        Assert.assertEquals(value,home_logo_url);
        driver.close();
        driver.switchTo().window(SiteWindow);
        System.out.println("Pass");

        System.out.println("Check for enough_talk_promo");
        driver.get(baseUrl + "/category/tournaments/");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='content']/div/div[4]/aside/div/div/p[1]/a")).click();
        for (String PromoWindow : driver.getWindowHandles())
        {
            driver.switchTo().window(PromoWindow); // switch focus of WebDriver to the next found window handle (that's your newly opened window)
        }
        String sr_enough_talk_promo = (String) ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(script);
        Assert.assertEquals(sr_enough_talk_promo,enough_talk_promo);
        driver.close();
        driver.switchTo().window(SiteWindow);
        System.out.println("Pass");


  }
```

[image: Here is field i had created]

How to iterated to each rows and get my test case run !!!

It is much helpful , if some one can convert my existing code to work on excel sheet .

Thanks

Comment: Did you [try reading the Apache POI documentation on iterating over rows and cells](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator)?

Comment: Yes i do , but not getting how to proceed , can you please convert my existing script to read all element from excel and do necessary assertion

Comment: You appear to have mistaken this website for somewhere to do your job for you... :(

Answer (score 0):

i was working on a project in Spring that read from an excel (.xls) and this was my code if can help

```
private List<String> extraire (String fileName) throws IOException {
    List<String> liste = new ArrayList();
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(fileName));
    HSSFWorkbook  workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);
    HSSFSheet spreadsheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    Iterator < Row > rowIterator = null;
    rowIterator = spreadsheet.iterator();
    while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
        int i = 0;
        row =  (HSSFRow) rowIterator.next();
        Iterator < Cell > cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
        while ( cellIterator.hasNext()) {
            Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
            i++;
            /**
             * For verifying if a line is empty
             */
            if (i % 29 == 0 || i == 1) {
                while ( cellIterator.hasNext() && cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK) {
                    cell = cellIterator.next();
                }
            }

            switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                    String cellule = String.valueOf(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                    liste.add(cellule);
                    break;
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                    liste.add(cell.getStringCellValue());
                    break;
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
                     cellule = " ";
                             liste.add(cellule);
                             break;
            }
        }
    }
        fis.close();
        return liste;
}
```

in my controller :

```
List<String> liste = new ArrayList();
liste = extraire(modelnom);

for (int m=0, i=29;i<liste.size();i=i+29) {
    if(i % 29 == 0) {
        // i=i+29 : begin from the second line first coll 
        // m is line
        m++;
    }

String matricule = (String)liste.get(29*m).toString().trim();
float mat = Float.parseFloat(matricul); // From String to float
employe.setMatricule((int)mat); //reading mat as an int

// ... your Code
}
```

Comment: Thanks . i had founded that code , but not getting how to click on element specify in excel sheet

Comment: i update the code if can help, first code is how i read from Excel and the second is how i insert that value to my empoye table in DB

Comment: I had tried it but not able to modify  your code according to my requirement , ..Can you please make for me so that i can refer and go forward